Going from Evaluation to Developer for 1 day?
We have an SQL Server that won't start, error code 17051 - Evaluation expired.
We will be licensing it, but I don't have access to the billing and the person who does will not be around until after we need this to start.
What is the big difference from eval to developer if I run it in developer just to get operations going? Are there any features that will be removed or any limitations in place?
I have no intention of doing something illegal, hence the questions and information gathering. This landed on my plate while someone's on vacation and I haven't dealt with SQL Servers before.

The Developer Edition has all the features enabled that Enterprise Edition offers. The only functional difference I'm aware is that version info (available with select @@version, and select serverproperty('Edition')) do return a string containing Developer Edition. There's also a limit for one client only for distributed replay, which is a deprecated feature.
From technical point of view, there are two caveats. If you plan to run Standard Edition, don't enable features that are available only in the Enterprise Edition. Doing so will make migration to SE more complicated. Some applications check SQL Server's edition, explicitly look for production editions and refuse to work with a Developer Edition.
The big limitation is that using the Developer Edition in production blatantly violates Microsoft's licensing terms.
